# Should we allow general workflow questions that don't directly relate to blender?

Tags: discussion

Should questions about general 3D workflow that don't specifically relate to blender be allowed?

For example questions where the OP does not use blender:

e.g. [How to fix a 6 point vertex](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5239/599)

Comment: Related, [General 3D Graphics](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55/general-3d-graphics).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any problem with accepting these questions as long as they don't ask about features specific to other softwares.

Comment: General CG questions are allowed as long as they aren't overly broad.

Comment: ...or comparing different programs.

Comment: I don't have a problem with workflow questions either, but how do we distinguish them from tutorial requests?

Comment: @Matt I would think [the same way we normally do](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/62/599). E.g. there is a difference between "How to make an airplane", and "How to add lowpoly windows to an airplane"

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen that post. Thanks.