# Should questions that don't directly relate to blender, but are about general artistic topics like composition be on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example, this question: [How to use the golden spiral composition rule](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17959/599).

These [are already allowed](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/312/599) for general CG/modeling questions. One could argue that composition is a part of CG, but on the other hand composition also applies to lots of non-CG art forms too.

Are these kinds of questions on or off topic?

Comment: Again, related - http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/59/12. General CG is fine to a certain point but the flat theory is a bit borderline IMO. This question would probably be better off on [photography.se](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composition).

Comment: Searching photo.se also turned up this [What is the 'Golden Ratio' and why is it better than the 'Rule of Thirds?'](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/8965).